# How to set my url only available for a period of time? React

Tags: html, reactjs, url, server, jet

I am working on my react project and I need one page of my website only available for like 5 minutes.

For an instance, I will send user an email which contain an `url`, user can visited the `webpage` by clicking url. However, after a certain period of time (like 5 minute), user cannot access the `webpage` by clicking url anymore (which means the url is useless.)

How should I create such webpage with url in my React project?

Comment: This has to be handled on the server side

Comment: Really appreciate! Could you please give me any hint about how to handled on server? (I used nextjs)

Comment: Are you running a custom server with next? Like, say express?

Comment: Yes I am running a custom server.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656460/expire-my-link-after-x-hour-nodejs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expire my link after X hour nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656460/expire-my-link-after-x-hour-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to do this on your server. Say you have a route that looks like this, `/verification/:id` and you send an email to the user with a link routing them to `https://my-site/verification/cd5d00c4-ff6c-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1`. When the email is sent you can store that string, `cd5d00c4-ff6c-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1` in your database and set a timer to remove it from the database after a specified amount of time if it's still there. When someone navigates to `/verification/:id` you take the id and see if it exists in your database. If it does, let them verify and then remove it from the database.